# Overflow:hidden making hidden the pseudo element itself

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the below layout using pseudo-element for the upper curve  but there is a problem in doing this

[image]

I have tried this

```css
ul li{
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid #bcbcbc;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.upper{
  height: 200px;
}
.bottom{
  background: #000;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bottom:before
{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top:-50px;
 border-bottom:25px solid #000;
 content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #000;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 150px solid transparent;
    border-right: 150px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
   <li>
     <div class="upper"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I put overflow hidden for `.bottom` class it's hiding the pseudo-element itself. please point where I am doing wrong

Comment: thanks for the answers I got how to do and I did that,  but still I didn't get the reason the pseudo-element itself hiding.

Comment: because you placed the pseudo element outside its parent element using negative top value ... to fix your code remove `width:100%` from the pseudo element and `overflow:hidden` from parent element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it without `pseudo` element using `skew()` method:

```css
ul li{
  width: 300px;
  height:400px ;
  border: 5px solid #bcbcbc;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.parent{
 overflow:hidden;
     position:relative;
     height:100%;
     width:100;
     }

.bottom{
  background: #000;
  height: 400px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-200px;
  left:0;
  transform:skewY(-15deg)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
   <li>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="bottom"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but there is no space between border and inner divs

Comment: now its working like you want!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change the width of *bottom:before* pseudo element to auto instead of 100% and remove `overflow:hidden` property from bottom class.

Check the snippet below

```css
ul li{
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid #bcbcbc;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.upper{
  height: 200px;
}
.bottom{
  background: #000;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.bottom:before
{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top:-50px;
 border-bottom:25px solid #000;
 content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #000;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    width: auto;
    border-left: 150px solid transparent;
    border-right: 150px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
   <li>
     <div class="upper"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the correct way is to use clip-path as [demonstrated here](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms/)

Answer (score 0):

add this css in your bootom class

```
.bottom{
  background: #000;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: polygon(0 38%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

Comment: check working demo here https://jsfiddle.net/bt2e1nky/

Comment: nice didn't know this trick, do you now perhaps if you can make this work for Edge & IE?

Comment: Note `clip-path` does not work at all in microsoft browsers and may have issues in other browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path